# How to update the 2nd and 3rd character in string with X

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an employee table with the columns first name and last name. I need to mask the data. I need to replace 2nd and 3rd character with X.

```
update employee 
set last_name = 
Stuff(last_name, CharIndex(LEFT(last_name,1), last_name), Len(LEFT(last_name,1)), 'X') 
from Employee where Employee_Id = 'A.Abrahams'
```

The update is not working. Can any one help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
update employee 
set last_name =  stuff(last_name, 2, 2, 'XX') 
where Employee_Id = 'A.Abrahams'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to replace positions 2 and 3, why not use the following:

```
update employee
set last_name = Stuff(last_name, 2, 2, 'X')
where ...
-- 'Abrahams' --> 'AXahams'
```

If you want to block out everything except the first and last characters, this might work:

```
update employee
set last_name = Stuff(last_name, 2, len(last_name)-2, 'X')
where len(last_name) > 2
and ...
-- 'Abrahams' --> 'AXs'
-- 'Doe' --> 'DXe'
```